# Open Another Page - HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

This is my whole html code, 
I do not understand why it does not open "example.html" page.
if someone can help me understand why.
I would like to make sure that when the credentials are correct and I press the login button it directs me to a new file (in this case "example.html"), but I do not know why nothing happens

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var message = "Right Click Disabled!";

        function rtclickcheck(keyp) {
            if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" &&
                keyp.which == 3) {
                alert(message);
                return false;
            }
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 && event.button == 2) {
                alert(message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;

        function check(form) {
            if (form.username.value == "admin" && form.password.value == "123") {
                window.open("example.html")
            } else {
                alert("Username Or Password Doesn't Match!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="form-box">
        <div class="head">LOGIN</div>
        <div id="textbox">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                <br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" name="btn_submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code, although kinda rough, does seem to be functioning correctly. Here's a fiddle with the important parts: https://jsfiddle.net/yta890x2/ -- clicking on the submit button does try to open the "example.html" page in a new window, assuming you enter the "admin" username and "123" password.

Comment: If the tab/window is not opening, have you checked if a popup blocker is blocking it?

Comment: @SuperUser You should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form submission cancels the redirect and vice versa. 
Use the below code instead:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css1.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var message = "Right Click Disabled!";
     function rtclickcheck(keyp) {
     if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" && keyp.which == 3) {
     alert(message);
     return false;
     }
     if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 && event.button == 2) {
     alert(message); return false;
     }
     }
     document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;

     function check(form)
     {
         if(form.username.value == "admin" && form.password.value == "123")
         {
             window.location.replace("example.html");
            return false;
         } else
         {
             alert("Username Or Password Doesn't Match!");
            return false;
         }
     }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-box">
     <div class="head">LOGIN</div>
     <div id="textbox">
        <form onsubmit="return check(this);">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
           <br>
           <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
           <br>
           <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Login">
        </form>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it does not work anyway, but in online sites it works properly.

Comment: Are you using the exact same code above? Are there any errors in the console? Try debugging from the console, also instead of using example.html once try with an online site like http://google.com

Answer (score 1):

When you click the submit button, your form is submitted and the browser reloads the page (because you don't specify an action in your form).

You need to either prevent the submission viq JavaScript ([check out `Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
), or turn you submit input into a button with type button, so that clicking it does not submit the form.

```js
var message = "Right Click Disabled!";

function rtclickcheck(keyp) {
  if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" &&
    keyp.which == 3) {
    alert(message);
    return false;
  }
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 && event.button == 2) {
    alert(message);
    return false;
  }
}
document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;



function check(form) {

  if (form.username.value == "admin" && form.password.value == "123") {
    window.open("example.html")
  } else {
    console.log("Username Or Password Doesn't Match!");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="form-box">
    <div class="head">LOGIN</div>
    <div id="textbox">
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
        <br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" name="btn_submit">button</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is working fine.
Please make sure that example.html is also in the same path your login html page is located. Also check for popup blocker as mentioned by @Andrew_CSE